Script powershell - Synchronise local folders with remote directory with WinSCP
I'm writing a Powershell script using WinSCP where I want to synchronize all files that are put into a local folder (or folders) and whenever this happens it should be transfered/copied to a sftp server, remote directory.
I tried the following but this only detects it but doesn't copy it to the sftp server directory. Thank you in advance for the help.
# Parameters for local and remote directories
$localFolder = "D:\SOMETHING\REG"
$remoteFolder = "/LOCATION/SENT/"

# WinSCP executable path (adjust as necessary)
$winscpPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"

# SFTP connection details
$sftpHost = "sftp.eservices.something.eu"
$sftpUsername = "USER"
$sftpPassword = "password"
$sftpSessionName = "SFTP_Session"

# Function to synchronize files using WinSCP
function Synchronize-WithWinSCP {
    param (
        [string]$localPath,
        [string]$remoteFolder
    )
    
    Write-Host "Connecting to SFTP server ($sftpHost)..."
    
    $scriptBlock = {
        param($winscpPath, $sftpUsername, $sftpPassword, $sftpHost, $sftpSessionName, $localPath, $remoteFolder)
        & "$winscpPath" `
            /log="winscp.log" `
            /command `
            "open sftp://${sftpUsername}:${sftpPassword}@${sftpHost} -sessionname ${sftpSessionName}" `
            "lcd \`"$localPath\`"" `
            "cd \`"$remoteFolder\`"" `
            "put \`"$localPath\`"" `
            "exit"
    }
    
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command & { $scriptBlock }" -PassThru
}

# Monitor folder for file creations
$folderWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$folderWatcher.Path = $localFolder
$folderWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$folderWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

# Define the event action when a new file is created
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $folderWatcher -EventName Created -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    Write-Host "File created: $name"
    
    # Synchronize the new file to remote directory
    Synchronize-WithWinSCP -localPath $path -remoteFolder $remoteFolder
}

# Function to stop monitoring and clean up
function Stop-FolderWatcher {
    $folderWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $onCreated.Name
}

Write-Host "Monitoring folder '$localFolder' for file additions..."
Write-Host "Press Ctrl+C to exit."

# Keep the script running until interrupted
try {
    while ($true) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5  # Check every 5 seconds
    }
}
finally {
    Stop-FolderWatcher
}

